# Making citep behave like cite

Tags: citing

I need to modify a very long document so that it no longer uses natbib (in order to conform to publisher requirements). I tried redefining \citep to be identical to \cite, but it doesn't seem to be working. The command I used was

```
\newcommand{\citep}[1]{\cite{#1}}
```

Could anyone tell me if this is correct? (Thanks!)

Comment: No it is not, `\cite` can take many more options, you might get away with just `\let\citep\cite`, but you should check for any double optional options given to `\citep`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just make this into an answer that you can accept, then the question no longer sits unanswered.

No it is not, `\cite` can take many more options, you might get away with just `\let\citep\cite`, but you should check for any double optional options given to `\citep`